# select menu inside <li> working on ios chrome but not on ios safari

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

i am working on a responsive web app which has a menu of cities and under it there are many options.
on desktop it uses `ul > li > a` but on smaller screens, it hides `<a>` and make select/option menu visible
.
the issue i'm facing is that it is working fine in Android. even perfect in ios chrome. But in ios safari i have to DOUBLE TAP the list/select item to open a select/option menu
.
here is the code

```
<ul> <li id="12">
            <a href="/fashion-collections/2014/1-spring-summer/1-ready-to-wear/12-kiev">Kiev</a>
            <select class="designer-mobile-dropdown">
              <option>
                Kiev
              </option>
              <option value="/anna-k-ready-to-wear-spring-summer-2014-kiev-4971">
                Anna K
              </option>
              <option value="/natasha-zinko-ready-to-wear-spring-summer-2014-kiev-4945">
                Natasha Zinko
              </option>
              <option value="/omelya-atelier-ready-to-wear-spring-summer-2014-kiev-4948">
                Omelya Atelier
              </option>
              <option value="/paskal-ready-to-wear-spring-summer-2014-kiev-4954">
                Paskal
              </option>
              <option value="/sasha-kanevski-ready-to-wear-spring-summer-2014-kiev-4960">
                Sasha Kanevski
              </option>
              <option value="/yasya-minochkina-ready-to-wear-spring-summer-2014-kiev-4951">
                Yasya Minochkina
              </option>
            </select>
          </li> </ul>
```

on smaller screen:

```
ul > li > a { display: none }
```

i've also given some `transition` effect which works fine in ios chrome but not in ios safari

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #777   
background: rgba(255,255,255,1)
z-index: 5
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s
transition: all 1s ease 0s
```

DOUBLE TAP means: on the 1st tap over `li > select`, it runs transition then on 2nd tap, it opens ios native select/option menu.
i have to make it open on single tap !

Answer (score 0):

fortunately i've resolved it somehow.
i had **:hover** enabled in CSS and i guess it was the cause of the problem in ios safari.

when i commented it for smaller sized devices using media query, it worked for me.
now running perfect on ios safari as well as ios chrome